# How can i insert information to a text file in two separate columns?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to make a little "money manager" program that keeps track of my withdrawals and deposits each month. I would like to be able to write this information to a text file where i have one column for withdrawals and another for deposits. I think this would be easy if each withdrawal was accompanied with a deposit but that is not my case.

The reason i want to have the file formatted this way is so that when i tell the program to give me a full summary i can see my withdrawals on the left and my deposits on the right. I'm starting to think that a simple textfile is not what i want to use for this program. Should i try to use an excel spreadsheet or a table in an rdms?

Comment: Why not use a pre-made financial tracking app? There are plenty of freeware and cheap shareware apps readily available.

Comment: Well, i'm just trying to teach myself some c++ and the best way for me to learn a language is to use it on small projects that i can actually use on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than display the raw file itself, you should read the file data into memory and display it in a UI Grid or ListView control that give you proper columns to work with.  Don't try to format the data itself (I wouldn't use a text file this either, use a binary file), format the display of the data instead.

Comment: Why a binary file instead of text ?

Comment: Using a binary file makes it easier for your code to manage the file data. If you are going to display the file data in a UI, it doesn't matter what the format of the file is, since the app has to read and interpret the data into a format that the UI understand. So you should make it easier for your code to manage the data. Making the file textual is only useful if you intend to edit the file by hand outside of your app.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would solve this is by storing the change to the account - positive values means money into the account, negative values taking money out of the account.

If you wish to show that in two columns, then you can display the it with more spaces for withdrawals than for deposits.

Comment: so let's say i had 3 withdrawals and one deposit. They each would still be on a separate line but with the spacing it would look like they are separated into columns. That's what you mean right? I think that's a good idea actually.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Obviously, if they are on the same day, you could check for that and print it on the same column, but that's a nicety.

Comment: I think i'll go this route and then later on update the project to use the GUI option that @Remy Lebeau suggested. If only i could choose two best answers..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options I see:

- **Using an rdms**

Almost always it is not necessary to create elaborate file formats if you can push it into an sqlite-database.

For your application I think you would use one table with the colums (enum {deposit or withdrawal}, int amount_in_cent, timestamp).

- **Using a csv-file**

Writing a comma-separated file with "deposit,withdrawal,date" would be trivial. With a suitable program (awk) you can even print it with nice columns.

- **Using a tool made for the job**

gnucash exists :-)

- **Pretty printed format**

To expand on your proposal, you could specify one maximum amount (1 million dollars?) that you would move in one transaction and then separate the columns with 11 spaces (7 for the dollars, one for the comma, two for the cents and one for a trailing space). If you viewed that file as a text file, it would show pretty much what you want.

Ex.:

```
      2.97            Cat food
             10000.00 Salary
```